# styling a radiobutton list

Tags: asp.net, html, css, radio-button

I'm trying to style an asp.net radiobutton list however there doesnt appear to be any easy way around it. I want to change the circle to a circle with a colour in it.
The only way i could get rid of the default circle was to change the `-webkit-appearance` property to `'none'`. However this means I cannot select the radio button at all.
The radio buttons have the correct background image when I use this:

```
radiobutton.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("background",
                                    "url(/kisses/designs/colours/red.gif) no-repeat");
```

but this background is applied to the `span` and **not** the `input` element. there must be a much easier way around this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Styling form elements is very system and browser specific. If you really want to consistently change their display, the easiest way is with a Javascript library like [Uniform](http://uniformjs.com/).

Comment: ive been going through a few libraries now but none of them work properly with the asp.net radiobutton list. alot of them require divs around the radio buttons which asp.net doesnt generate.

Comment: I use Uniform with asp.net everyday, so no worries about that. It automatically wraps the `input` with the necessary `div`, that's one of the things that makes it so easy.

Comment: i used this in the end but still needed to do some css the make the list look right, uniform was good for making the deafult radiobutton image the browser creates disapear

Answer (score 1):

In fact there is - I often use this javascript replacement solution http://lipidity.com/fancy-form/

Works from IE6+ (ie6 included). If you prefer jQuery over Mootools just search jQuery custom checkbox or something like that on google - there are tons of other jquery based solutions. This is just my prefered one.